# Error displaying linked list data (missing last value)

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

I am working on implementing `linked list` to study data structure.There are many good resources on the Internet, but I still don't understand what part of my code does not work.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val=None):
        self.data = val
        self.Next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.size = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        temp = self.head
        alist = []
        while temp.Next is not None:
            alist.append(temp.data)
            temp = temp.Next
        return str(alist)

    def add(self, val):
        cur = self.head
        prev = None
        if cur is None:
            self.head = Node(val)
        else:
            while cur is not None:
                prev = cur
                cur = cur.Next
            prev.Next = Node(val)
        self.size += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    alist = LinkedList()
    for i in range(10):
        alist.add(i)
    print(alist)

""" [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

I expected it prints out [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] but it misses last element. Can anybody tell me what I missed on my `add` method please?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In `__repr__`, when `temp.data` is `9`, `temp.Next` is `None`, which fails the condition, and `9` is never added to `alist`. Change the condition to `while temp is not None`

Comment: I thought my `add` was wrong. Thank you

Comment: @Jay Consider either posting an answer or deleting your question :)

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, my original `add` method was like this,

```
def add(self, val):
    temp = Node(val)
    temp.Next = self.head
    self.head = temp
    self.size += 1
```

However, it adds elements reverse order, like [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]. So I changed my `add` to

```
def add(self, val):
        cur = self.head
        prev = None
        if cur is None:
            self.head = Node(val)
        else:
            while cur is not None:
                prev = cur
                cur = cur.Next
            prev.Next = Node(val)
        self.size += 1
```

I did not have problem to print out all elements inside of linked list previously, however new way does not print out last element. It was my `__repr__` problem not `add`. I changed my `__repr__`. Thank you @inspectorG4dget